# Probability of choosing 3 specific card out of 100 given 10 tries

Tags: probability

A deck of $100$ unique cards.

There are $3$ unique cards that I want to see.

Each time I draw a card then put it back to the deck after looking at it.

I will then repeat the process until I had done it $10$ times.

What is the probability that after this $10$ draws, I have looked at the $3$ unique cards?

Edit: Chance of drawing each card is $0.01$

Comment: One of the unique card can be drawn more than once ? In other words: Every card of the 3 has to be drawn at least once ?

Comment: yes, they can be drawn more than once and each of the 3 card is drawn at least once

Comment: Then you can use the converse probability: The probability that every card of the 3 is drawn at least once is ONE minus the probability that no card of the three is drawn in ten trials. Is it comprehensible ? Can you go on `?

Comment: Easier to find the probability that at least one of your three is not seen.  Inclusion-Exclusion works here.  The probability that a particular card is not seen is $\left(\frac {99}{100}\right)^{10}$ so multiply that by three, then subtract the probability that at least two cards are unseen, then add back the probability that all three are unseen.

Comment: @lulu Not really. The probability that none of the 3 particular card are seen in one trial is 97/100. And so on ...

Comment: @callculus do you meant $1-(97/100)\^10$?

Comment: @Kakayou Yes. That´s right: $1-\left(\frac{97}{100}\right)^{10}$

Comment: 0.00072, i think

Comment: @callculus  Not following.  $1-\left(\frac {97}{100}\right)^{10}$ is the probability that at least one of your favorite three is observed.

Comment: that would be around 26% which is rather high, or am I missing something here

Comment: @lulu It seems your are right. Please go on I have to watch the europe cup. The german team is playing.

Comment: @callculus  Go Germany!

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Your Encouraging helped. Now I´m looking forward to the semi-final. For today it is interesting how the team of Iceland will play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ denote the probability you want and let $q=1-p$.  It is somewhat easier to compute $q$, the probability that at least one of your favorite three cards is not observed.

To compute $q$:  Note that the probability that a given card is not seen is clearly $\left( \frac {99}{100}\right)^{10}$.  The probability that neither of two (distinct) specified cards is seen is, similarly, $\left( \frac {98}{100}\right)^{10}$.  And the probability that none of your three (distinct) chosen cards is seen is $\left( \frac {97}{100}\right)^{10}$.  By the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion we get $$q=3\times \left( \frac {99}{100}\right)^{10}-3\times \left( \frac {98}{100}\right)^{10}+\left( \frac {97}{100}\right)^{10}\sim 0.999351931$$

Finally, $$p=1-q\sim \fbox {0.000648069}$$

Answer (score 1):

You could work out the following recursion.

Let $p\left(n,k\right)$ denote the probability that after $n$ draws
$k$ of the $3$ specific cards are seen.

Then you are looking for $p\left(10,3\right)$.

Here $p\left(n,k\right)=0$ if $n<k$ and $p(n,0)=1$ and:

$p\left(n,k\right)=\frac{k}{100}p\left(n-1,k-1\right)+\left(1-\frac{k}{100}\right)p\left(n-1,k\right)$.

---

Another route (suggested by @Lulu)

For $i=1,2,3$ let $E_{i}$ denote the event that card $i$ is not
seen after $10$ draws. Applying inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:

$$P\left(E_{1}^{c}\cap E_{2}^{c}\cap E_{3}^{c}\right)=1-P\left(E_{1}\cup E_{2}\cup E_{3}\right)=$$$$1-3P\left(E_{1}\right)+3P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)-P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\cap E_{3}\right)$$

That is definitely more handsome than my former suggestion. Credit to @Lulu.